# HTML5 geolocation - not working on Android

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

The project I'm working on uses smartphones with Android (can't tell what version but it's recent) to find the user's current position. However, at the moment, it brings up the "share current position" allow/reject question, but then does nothing. If you leave it on that then the page in the background reloads after a bit, and if you allow it then it reloads in any case. It should bring up the location in a message prompt.

I will point out that this works on an iPhone I've had access to, and in IE10 (I think it is).

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLocate" Text="Loc" OnClientClick="return GetLocation()" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">

            function GetLocation()
            {
                if (navigator.geolocation)
                {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(ShowPosition, ShowError, { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 31000, maximumAge: 90000 });
                }
                else{alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");}
            }
            function ShowPosition(position)
            {
                alert(position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude);
                return false;
            }
            function ShowError(error)
            {
                switch(error.code) 
                {
                    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                        alert("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
                        break;
                    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                        alert("Location information is unavailable.");
                        break;
                    case error.TIMEOUT:
                        alert("The request to get user location timed out.");
                        break;
                    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                        alert("An unknown error occurred.");
                        break;
                }
            }
        </script>
```

I should also mention that GPS is enabled and Google Maps is able to find the location just-about instantly.

Comment: If you set enableHighAccuracy to false, does it work?

Comment: Nope, given that a go (as well as increased the timeout). It basically seems like it must refresh after a few seconds, regardless of if the allow button is pressed or not.

Comment: Is there a URL we can test this at?

Comment: Afraid not - it's got to be quite secure due to the sensitivity of it and the information we're hosting. Sorry! I've just tried the following options (enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 120000, maximumAge: 60000) and it's still not working, but is refreshing quicker.

Comment: I've simplified the code but it's still not working. I think I'm finding WHERE the problem is - seemingly it's not actually managing to call the ShowPosition - it gets to the question but stops there.

Comment: How about adding alert("hello world"); before the alert showing coordinates. Maybe you typoed there.

Comment: Hi Raymond - also done that. It doesn't seem to be getting into the ShowPosition at all, strangely. I've done some research and wandering if it has something to do with it being asynchronous and hence we need something to "catch" the returned coordinates. Which is strange because, as I pointed out, it works on iPhones and through IE10.

Comment: I'm now thinking it's to do with the browser exclusively. As I said, it works on an iPhone and in IE10. However, in Android (or at least on the phone I'm trying - Samsung Galaxy S3 with some stuff locked down, and our IT dept is saying it's nothing they've done) it seems to want to refresh the page when the "Location requested - allow/deny" box appears. I think it may be the software that locks stuff down because the allow/deny box is blue and not the regular browser colours. I'll try it on my phone (trusty old Samsung Galaxy Ace) tonight - can't try it at the moment as my network's rubbish.

Comment: Well a few things here. Yes, geolocation is asynch. That's why you specify handlers for success/errors. Android web browsers have no problem with that in general so that isn't the issue. To your second issue about the Allow/Deny, this is *also* expected and is part of the browser just being secure.

Comment: How about this - since you can't share your code - keep taking stuff out until you get to a version you CAN share, and then tell us that.

Comment: Sorry Raymond - it's not an issue with sharing code, it's the data. The page also accesses data we want kept secure. Meanwhile, I've just tried it again on the iPhone and deduced it's not an Android issue. Even on the iPhone, when the "allow/deny" box appears, the page refreshes in the background (takes it a few seconds but it does - it's just that the location was pretty much there already which is why I thought it worked perfectly on the iPhone). Weird but I think that it's this mysterious page refresh causing this problem.

Comment: Bam - I see it. Ok, give me a minute.

Comment: The issue is that your button, the one to get location, is *also* submitting the form. You don't want that. Either "return false" in getLocation or if using jQuery, you can preventDefault on the event objhect.

Comment: Ooo - this could work, and if I could get it in the next 10 mins (leaving soon) would be great. Do I use the return false in the call to the function?

Comment: Let me address it in a Answer below, so you can mark it right and get me points. ;)

Comment: Was just about to suggest that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with his code is that the button was acting as a form submit action. So even though the browser paused to prompt for the OK, as soon as it was out of the way a form submission was fired. Adding return false to the end of handler *should* correct it (basically saying, "Dont submit this form"). I don't know ASP.Net very well so that may not be it exactly.

Comment: Sorted, thank you very much. The code is the same as above, except for as you pointed out, the button, which is now <asp:Button ID="btnLocate" Text="Loc" OnClientClick="GetLocation(); return false;" runat="server" /> (note the return false in the function call). Thanks a lot, this is absolutely perfect!